# Error on registration of .dll module

Tags: windows-10, dll, regsvr32

What reason might be behind this error message during installing the MAGIX-software and failing on it

-> Error on registration of module C:\Program Files\Common Files\MAGIX Services\System\MediaExchangeProxy_x64.dll

The .dll is found present on the folder, so the missing is not an explanation on this.

Testing the registration of it on another machine with regsvr32 there didn't arise any problem.

The original machine is Windows 10 Home 64-bit 1511 10586.493 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this problem did vanish upon installing the Windows 10 Upgrade version 1607, needed to be done also for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Please disable the security software or create an exception while installing the software. Also disconnect the internet while security is disabled.

Here's the source: https://support2.magix.com/customer/en/installation_problems

Comment: OK, thanks, but this hint has already been tried with no success. We are expecting some more instructions from MAGIX.